# Arduino clone not recognized

Tags: arduino, clone, bootloader, arduino-uno

I recently purchased an Arduino clone. Looks very much like the original. It is written that it is an Arduino Uno and the microcontroller has a chip that goes by the name of ATMEGA32BP-PU. I plugged it into my PC and was able to make an LED blink out of a voltage that comes from the 13th pin, this was by uploading the example code, even when it worked there was an error message shown:

> avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\.\COM1": The system cannot find the file specified.

This error message kept coming even when I changed the code. What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: Are you sure you selected the correct port for the device?

Comment: Are you using a usb hub or a usb extension as once I had problems with a usb extension. Removed it and worked as it should.